# jjquery code snippet to validate telephone number input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

So I'm using Knack and a Jquery code snippet to extend the Knack featureset. I want to validate a telephone number entered into a form on Knack. Knack provide this code example, but it doesn't do quite what I want it to do.

```
    // Your app's ViewID and FieldID will need updated.
$(document).on('knack-view-render.view_97', function(event, view, data) {

  $("#view_97 .kn-submit input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    // if this value in my form doesn't equal "SpecificValue" then prevent the form from submitting
    if ($("#view_2-field_29").val() != "SpecificValue") { 
     alert ("These are not the droids you are looking for.");
     return false;
    }
  })

})
```

Basically I would like the validation to either strip out (preferred) or not accept (next best!) spaces and insist on being given a mobile number which is either " " (a space) or a number in the format 00000000000. 11 digits.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Thanks Tushar, looks perfect! But would I just substitute
!= "SpecificValue") for
!= /\s|\d{11}$/) ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to use it directly on `input` element as `pattern="\s|\d{11}"`

Comment: hmm, I don't have direct access to the input element. I can presumably modify it through the use of code, but I can't just insert that pattern into the HTML element unfortunately. I will continue to Google and see if I can figure out how to adjust it using the above code snippet as a guide. Thanks so much.

Comment: Okay, use `test`, `regex.test(string)`

Comment: OK, so I've done this

`$(document).on('knack-view-render.view_23', function(event, view, data) {
  $("#view_23.kn-submit input[type=submit]").on("click", function() {
    if ($("#view_23-field_32").val() =!isValidmobilenumber(mobilenumber)) {
      alert("These are not the droids you are looking for.");
    }
    return false;
  })
})

function isValidmobilenumber(mobilenumber) {
  var pattern = new RegExp(/\s|\d{11}/)
  return pattern.test(mobilenumber);
}`

but apparently the left side of the argument is invalid. I feel like I'm nearly there! Any tips? THANK YOU  @Tushar!

Comment: @daneee, what line? Mind editing your question to include that code instead of it being in a comment (more readable)? Also, [this](http://regexper.com/#%2F%5Cs%7C%5Cd%7B11%7D%2F) is a map of your regexp, if it helps.

Comment: @daneee: Do you just want to match a space or 11 digit string? Like `/^(?:\s|\d{11})$/`?

Answer (score 0):

To strip out any non-digits in the number and take the first 11:

```
$("#view_2-field_29").val().replace(/\D/g,"").slice(0,11)
```